# Oracle 11g is not installing in Windows 7 64bit

Tags: oracle11g

i had downloaded the latest version of oracle 11g 64 bit (which is compatible to my system) From oracle Website. while Installing the Oracle into my getting The Following Error.
 - java.lang.NullPointerException

what all i did ?
1. Double click on the setup Application File in the Database folder of Oracle 11g
2. i did not give the email details in Condigure Security Updates Pod.
3.In Installation Options i have selectd the Create and Configure a Database Option.
When i click on Next i am getting the Error
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: _"When i click on Next i am getting the Error ![enter image description here][1]"_... did you post a link for this; there isn't one in your post...

Comment: @Ben i tried to attach a image of the error but the stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do that as i don't have enough reputation to upload a image .

Comment: You can paste the link though. Someone else can ensure its turned into an image.

Comment: @ben : The Following link contains the image of the error .        link :http://www.mediafire.com/?u1p865w1em22rek

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem (mentioned in another thread I'm still looking for to respond), but it would fail (without notice) when selecting "desktop class" (step 3). We found that there was a problem with the included javaw.exe file, so used the following start line in the command line (from wherever setup.exe is located):

```
setup -jreLoc c:\PROGRA~1\java\jdk1.6.0_25
```

(Modify to reflect the location of an alternate JRE, like the one I used above.)

Hopefully this helps. If not, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Run the setup file as administrator with a user account that does not have an exclamation mark in it.

Answer (score -1):

After downloading both the files , Keep the second file in first file
In my case i copied the file in file2 in to file 1
from
D:....\win64_11gR2_database_2of2\database\stage\Components
to
D:....\win64_11gR2_database_1of2\database\stage\Components

and don't forgot to update Oraparm configuration settings file under install
according to your jre location and version